# Voting button contrast

Tags: feature-request, bug

I'm finding it pretty hard to see at a glance, whether I've voted here or not.  On other sites, it's not so bad, but the dark blue theme color for https://unix.stackexchange.com is especially close to the dark grey of not having voted.  That leaves only a very thing, 1px wide circle as an indicator.

I've been a member here for over 8 years and on SE network even longer and never had the current issue of continually clicking to vote, only to be told that I've done so already.

Can we please get a theme tweak or something on this site to help with the button contrast?

Comment: Recently: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7117/117549

Comment: Thanks. Oddly, I didn't find that on a search for "button contrast". Guess the search queries don't recognize plurals. I'm tempted to close my own question here as a dupe, but for the fact that I tagged it "feature-request".  Maybe it doesn't matter.  Should we close this one?